# Mastering Categories in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I have a budget with a Column for "Categories" and for "Amount". Within the Column for categories, as one might expect, is a category for "Groceries". Groceries is column "C" and Amount is column D.

In a separate column I typed the following formula:
=SUMIF(Category); "=Groceries); Amount

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you testing for the presence of the `Groceries` category label before adding the amount into your calculation? Are `Category` and `Amount` named collections/ranges?

The [format for `SUMIF`](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH802) is:

```
SUMIF(collection_to_test, "test condition", optional_collection_of_values_to_sum)
```

So assuming `Category` and `Amount` are named ranges, your formula should be:

```
=SUMIF(Category, "=Groceries", Amount)
```

If they are not named ranges, it would look like this:

```
=SUMIF(C2:C10, "=Groceries", D2:D10)
```

Naturally, substitute your own particular cell ranges for the first and last parameters.